# Problem for update multiples products in one http request using put

Tags: rest, api, woocommerce, product

How can I do for update multiples products in one request. For example I have more than 4000 products, I was using PUT with this endpoint https://www.bachmusic.center/wp-json/wc/v3/products/{id}

and the JSON body something like this.

```
    {
"sku":"{sku}",
"name":"{name}",
"price":"{regular_price}"
    }
```

but doesn't work.

The error is 404 not found.